# /dev/sdb2: No such file or directory

Tags: swap, devices, udev

I was trying to add a swap partition in my secondary drive, I created the partition space with fdisk and when running mkswap I was greeted with an error:

```
$ sudo mkswap -c /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2: No such file or directory
```

In fact the device doesn't exist:

```
$ ls /dev/sda*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5
$ ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

fdisk confirms me that the partition exists:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   419432447   209715200   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       419432448   429918207     5242880   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, I thought that udev would manage the devices automatically, should I still use MAKEDEV, or there is a new method to handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `sudo partprobe` in a terminal do anything? I believe fdisk is supposed to do it for you when you exit but maybe it didn't.

Anything in dmesg about the new partition or a reason why it hasn't added the device node?

MAKEDEV is not the answer. Even if it works temporarily, it'll be gone after a reboot if there's a deeper problem.

Comment: I just rebooted before I saw your answer and now the device is created, since I've more space in the device I will try to create a new one and test `partprobe`. Yes, I suspected in fact that MAKEDEV was obsoleted, that's why I posted the question. Thank you @Caesium.

Comment: I've created /dev/sdb3 and noticed *WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.* `sudo partprobe` took about 4 minutes to complete, after that `/dev/sdb3` was available.

Comment: Great :) 4 minutes sounds a fairly long time, maybe a suspect disk is taking a while to respond. I'd check the SMART details if I were you :)

Comment: I will check, but I think it's for the floppy, which I don't have: *Warning: Unable to open /dev/fd0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/fd0 has been opened read-only.* - Unfortunately seems there is something wrong with the BIOS which messes up the settings every time I start the PC.

Comment: The SMART short test said completed without error, I am now running a long test, with ETA 4h. Will see.. thanks.