# Newly created partition does not "exist"

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, swap

First of all, sorry if this question might seem dumb. I'm basically a beginner with Ubuntu, and I might have missed something obvious.

Basically I repartitioned a virtual hard drive (my Ubuntu Server is a VM on VirtualBox) from a 1GB size to a 2-partition drive, one 800M and one 200M. I intend to use the latter as a swap drive.

Here is how I proceeded :

1. I unmounted the original partition.
2. I reduced the file system size to 700 MB via resize2fs.
3. I deleted the partition via gdisk, then created a new 800 MB one.
4. I created a second partition with the 8200 code for swap.
5. I resized the file system size to the 1st partition size.

Now, if I try to activate the swap drive with:

```
mkswap /dev/sdb2
```

I get an error message "no such file or directory". Yet the partition exists, as a simple fdisk shows:

[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This whole process actually came from a course that I followed to the letter, yet I can't proceed past this.

Comment: type ls /dev/sdb* to see if /dev/sdb2 exists. Could be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/82909/

Comment: It didn't exist. I rebooted the server, just to see if it would change anything, and it did, not for the better though. There was an error and now Ubuntu launches in emergency mode. sdb2 is now listed in /etc/, though...  Edit: the plot thickens, when I try e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2, it tells me "sdb2 is mounted, aborting", but when I umount it and relaunch the command it tells me that it's mounted again:::?   **edit 2**: I forgot I had to turn the swap off... e2fsck tells me there's a bad magic number in a super-block, what does that mean?

Comment: `fsck` (meaning “file system check”) or `e2fsck` is useless on a swap partition as such a partition contains no filesystem.

Comment: e2fsck is for ext2/ext3/ext4 so the bad magic number error isn't the problem.

Comment: Looking into the journalctl, I found this: `mount: /var/data1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock` `Failed to mount /var/data1 with result 'exit-code'` So the mounting is the problem?

Comment: Ok, after many twists and turns, turns out the first partition was corrupt; I had to redo the whole process and now it's working. Thanks to all of you!